# Запятая перед союзом "и", соединяющим два предложения

Tags: запятые, и

> В прошлом нет никакой силы, она может быть только в настоящем. А это значит, что человек, который постоянно возвращается к своим воспоминаниям, растрачивает свои силы по пустякам(,) и их не хватает для его настоящего.

Является ли "А это значит" общим предложением для двух последующих, соединенных союзом "и" (следовательно, запятая не ставится)? Или же последнее предложение относится только к предыдущему, "вытекает из него"? Ведь если убрать середину, то смысл совсем не будет ясен: *А это значит, их не хватает для его настоящего.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не ставится, но по другому правилу. Попробуем для ясности убрать определительное придаточное и тогда получим:

**А это значит, **что** человек  растрачивает свои силы по пустякам **и (что)** их не хватает для его настоящего.**

Это СПП **с однородными изъяснительными придаточными, второй союз ЧТО опускается.** По правилу между однородными придаточными запятая не ставится. (Можно условно считать, "общим элементом" здесь является главное предложение).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) **запятая не ставится:** Отец мой говорил, **что** он не видывал таких хлебов **и что** нынешний год урожай отличный (Акс.); Чудилось, **будто** корчуют сразу весь лес и выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, поставил плюсик, но принимать пока его не буду, а то получится как с другим Вашим ответом, который мне понравился больше, а я уже принял первый ответ. Прочитал по ссылке, но меня всё же смущает то, что во всех примерах (даже в примечании, где говорится о вариантах для необходимого смысла) можно подставить опущенный союз перед вторым однородным придаточным и убрать первое, и всё будет читаться нормально. А в моём примере это не так.

Comment: А еще Вы говорите, что "запятая не ставится, но по другому правилу". А какое первое правило подразумевается? Общий второстепенный член? Я вроде тоже, честно не помню где, смотрел о том же, что и в ссылке.

Comment: Да, это правило для ССП, там действительно нужен общий элемент.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133 Второй союз в СПП пропускается часто, но и в вашем случае его можно подставить, просто предложение некрасиво (вернее, необычно)  читается с двумя союзами. Но все это непринципиально, Гласное  - это граматика. Если вы уверены, что это однородные придаточные, то запятая не ставится. Так что проверяйте грамматику.

Comment: можно, пожалуйста, ещё раз уточнить? Если я не уверен, что это однородн. придаточные, то проверять грамматику нужно подставляя союз? А на смысл не обращать внимания?

Answer (score 1):

Подпредложение — мой удобный термин, обозначающий часть сложного предложения.

В таких ситуациях — где вроде бы и есть связь обоих придаточных с общим подпредложением/второстепенным членом/вводным/служебным, но при этом есть связь придаточных(последовательная связь придаточных), — в таких ситуациях запятая между придаточными ставится.

Вот несколько примеров:

В давно минувшие времена здесь были селения черемисского народа, и жил среди них Могучий и славных богатырь Чумбулат.

Иногда дверь отворяли, и мальчишек пускали в переднюю.

Comment: Другими словами, если однородные подпредложения можно менять местами без потери смысла, то запятая не ставится. А если смысл меняется, то подпредложения не однородные и запятая ставится.

Comment: @Jim Korbett У меня к автору ответа такие вопросы. 1. Где в ваших примерах вы увидели ПРИДАТОЧНЫЕ? Это сложносочиненные предложения (ССП), а придаточные бывают в сложноподчиненных предложениях (СПП). 2. Вы умеете определять ОДНОРОДНЫЕ придаточные? Это придаточные одного вида, отнесенные к одному слову в главном предложении или ко всему главному предложению. Если вы установили однородность придаточных, то вам больше не о чем беспокоиться, в этом случае запятая однозначно не ставится.

Comment: 3. Изобретать новые термины – занятие не слишком благодарное, это все равно что изобретать велосипед. Если уж говорить об общем элементе в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП), то там есть другие способы определить такой элемент, и обычно это несколько факторов, а не какой-то универсальный прием.  4. Можно переделать второе предложение: Иногда дверь отворяли и пускали мальчишек в переднюю. Где запятая? Нет запятой, а последовательность действий присутствует. Работают ваши подпредложения?

Comment: Я же не заставляю кого-то использовать мои термины. Просто, по-моему, неправильно говорить «часть сложного предложения», так как любое слово или сочетание слов в сложном предложении — часть сложного предложения. Неправильно говорить «главное предложение», так как предложение с несколькими основами называется «предложение», и при этом часть его также называется «предложением».   Термин «подпредложение» очень удобен. 
Про предложение о мальчишках. Я не очень понимаю, о чем речь. Данный пример взят из учебника.

Comment: Если вы думаете, что «отворяли и пускали» — однородные сказуемые, то — нет. В первом «подпредложении» основа — «открывали», во втором — «пускали мальчишек». Если существительное подвергается воздействию глагола в страдательном залоге, то оно считается подлежащим.
Я опять же не очень понимаю о чем вы пишете: то там нет придаточных, то они уже однородные придаточные.

Comment: По отношению к друг другу они сложносочиненные. Если считать, что оба «подпредложения» относятся к «подпредложению»: «А это значит», то они придаточные по отношению к нему.  Да, их нельзя называть придаточными по отношению к друг другу. Тут вы совершенно правы. А как назвать части сложносочиненного предложения по отношении к друг другу?
К сожалению, грамотеи пока не ввели термин для этого. 

По поводу запятой. Помимо двух примеров из учебника, я встречал десятки предложений с подобной языковой ситуацией, и всегда в таких ситуациях ставилась запятая.

Comment: Что-то Вы перемудрили, Jim Korbett! Нет в учебниках такого предложения (_Иногда дверь отворяли, и мальчишек пускали в переднюю_). Есть совершенно другое: **Иногда дверь отворялась, и их пускали в переднюю** (А. Куприн. Бедный принц). (http://translatyr.org/librusec/574353#TOC_idp1564488704)

Comment: Я могу дать ссылку на бесплатную книгу и назвать страницу, но в этом нет необходимости, так как в вашем примере присутствует запятая.

Comment: Неужели Вы не видите, что предложения **разные**? И пунктуация в них тоже может быть разной.

Comment: Jim Korbett, вы нам предлагаете новый  авторский курс грамматики с собственными определениями и правилами в вашей редакции? Я полагаю, что этот форум - не та площадка, где приветствуются подобные упражнения. Пржалуйста, не надо этим заниматься. На все ваши сообщения на грамматические темы прилагайте ссылки на авторитетные и проверенные источники. Пожалуйста, делайте это в обязательном порядке, у нас так принято. Прочитайте еще раз вопрос и дайте нормальный ответ. Это означает, что вы определяете вид предложения и объясняете постановку или отсутствие запятой. Также нужна ссылка на правило.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарий

**1. Сложноподчиненные предложения (СПП)**

Я бы не стала использовать для проверки однородных придаточных союз И, мне этот способ не кажется надежным и убедительным.  По определению **однородные придаточные** должны относиться к одному главному предложению (или к одному слову в главном предложении) и быть одного вида (изъяснительные, определительные. времени, причины и т.д.)

Но бывают сложные предложения, включающие разные виды подчинения. Пожалуй, здесь можно применить такой способ. Всего существует **три варианта подчинительных отношений:** (1) параллельное однородное, (2) параллельное неоднородное и  (3) последовательное.

**(1) Параллельное однородное.** *[А это значит], (что человек растрачивает свои силы по пустякам) и (что их не хватает для его настоящего).* **Два** придаточных **одного** вида (союз ЧТО)  относятся **к одному** слову в главном предложении «значит».

**(2) Параллельное неоднородное.** **(КОГДА наступила весна), [мы решили], (ЧТО пора отправляться в путь).** К **одному** главному предложению относятся **два** придаточных **разного вида** (времени и изъяснительное).

**(3) Последовательное подчинение.** *[Мы решили], (ЧТО отправимся в путь), (КОГДА наступит весна).* Здесь второе предложение является придаточным по отношению к первому предложению и главным предложением по отношению к третьему предложению.

**2. Сложносочиненные предложения (ССП)**

Понятие **однородное сочинение** существует и для ССП, но там оно касается только **двух видов предложений**: (1) со значением одновременных или последовательных во времени событий (интонация перечислительная); (2) сопоставительные предложения с союзом А. **Они полностью независимы между собой**, их можно **переставлять местами**, всякая взаимообусловленность отсутствует (или просто не рассматривается).

Например:  *Наступила весна, стало теплее, прилетели птицы.  Солнце светит, небо чистое, ветра почти нет. Сестра занимается музыкой, а брат ходит в спортивную школу.*

Все остальные ССП считаются **неоднородными**,  так как определенная взаимообусловленность (время, причина, уступка, условие и т.д.) там присутствует, хотя и не обозначена подчинительными союзами.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. В комментарии я имел в виду подстановку не союза И, а такого же союза, как в первом придаточном (т. е. ЧТО), о чём Вы писали в первом ответе. Простите, что не так меня поняли.

Comment: Да ладно, ничего. А про подчинительные союзы я уже говорила. Они могут присутствовать, а могут пропускаться. Иногда они легко восстанавливаются, иногда предложение с подставленным союзом выглядит не очень корректно. Особенно часто пропускаются сложные союзы, например ТАК ЧТО. Но в любом случае ясно, что один и тот же союз относится и к первому,  и ко второму придаточному. А смысловое содержание однородных придаточных действительно разное. Например, для одной причины мы можем назвать два разных следствия