# Разное управление глагола в одном предложении (А. И. Куприн)

Tags: управление, однородные-члены, дополнение

> Иногда дверь отворялась, и их пускали в переднюю. Тогда они начинали длинную, почти бесконечную колядку о том, как шла царевна на крутую гору, как упала с неба звезда-красна, как Христос народился, а Ирод сомутился. **Им выносили отрезанное щедрой рукой кольцо колбасы, яиц, хлеба, свиного студня, кусок телятины.** В другие дома их не пускали, но высылали несколько медных монет.
> [А. И. Куприн. Бедный принц](http://kuprin.velchel.ru/?cnt=8&story=sf_8&page=3)

Предложение попалось совершенно случайно ([Запятая перед союзом “и”, соединяющим два предложения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463571/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и заинтересовало тем, что однородные дополнения в нём имеют разные падежи (Р. п. и В. п.).
Подскажите, всё правильно или это приём такой, особенный?

[Словарная статья ([выноси́ть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)) понимания не добавила.]

Comment: Иногда, однородными могут быть даже разные члены предложения. Подлежащие и обстоятельство, например. Придумайте такое предложение если интересно.

Comment: "Выглядит как силлепс" -- без запятой перед как, потому что связка незнаменательная и как входит в сказуемое?

Comment: Подлежащее и обстоятельство — ну зачем же придумывать? Есть классическое предложение, которое в качестве примера используется во многих справочниках (правда, неполное). Целое выглядит так: _Неизвестно, **кто** и **как** разнес по тайге весть о гибели старого сокжоя, а на его тризне уже побывало немало гостей_ (Г. А. Федосеев. В тисках Джугдыра).

Comment: @user190920: ну зачем же запятую ставить после "иногда"!)

Comment: @user190920 Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на формулировку вопроса. Спрашивается о разном глагольном управлении для членов однородного ряда со стороны одного глагола, а не об однородности членов  как таковой.

Answer (score 3):

***Им выносили отрезанное щедрой рукой кольцо колбасы, яиц, хлеба, свиного студня, кусок телятины.***

**Цитата из комментария** (в качестве вступления):

"**Выглядит как силлепс с синтаксической неоднородностью:** технически члены неоднородные, но используются в перечислении. Хотя возможно тут просто опускается непосредственно счетный элемент при родительном падеже. Вынесли не просто яиц а какое-то количество яиц. Однородность подразумевается, но не выражена текстом". – JKlen

**Часть1. Силлепс? Нет, это не силлепс.**

1. Вам нравится  слово **силлепс?** Пр-моему, очень красивое! Как, вы никогда его не слышали? Но ничего, это не проблема, в современном информационном пространстве можно найти всё.

**Силле́пс** (др.-греч. σύλληψις «захват») — **стилистическая фигура,** синтаксическое оформление **семантически неоднородных** элементов в виде ряда однородных членов предложения. Силлепс в произведениях **возвышенного стиля** производит впечатление взволнованности, небрежности, в рамках же **«низкой стилистики»** эффект силлепса — комический.

Примеры:

**с синтаксической неоднородностью**: «Мы любим славу, да в бокале топить разгульные умы» (А. С. Пушкин, «Дельвигу») — объединены дополнения, выраженные одно существительным, другое — инфинитивом;

**с фразеологической неоднородностью:** «У кумушки глаза и зубы разгорелись» (И. А. Крылов, «Лисица и виноград») — фразеологизм «глаза разгорелись» и внефразеологическое слово «зубы»;

**с семантической неоднородностью:** «И звуков и смятенья полн» (А. С. Пушкин, «Поэт») — объединяются душевное состояние и его причина;

для комического эффекта: «Шли дождь и два студента: один в университет, другой в пальто.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Силлепс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%81)

2. И сразу становится ясно, что это **не силлепс** в его классическом понимании. Не ставил перед собой писатель характерной для силлепса  задачи, нет там **ни высокого стиля, ни комического эффекта.** Да и семантика здесь **однородная**.

**Часть 2. Ответ на вопрос**

Но почему тогда одинаковую семантику выражают **разные грамматические формы**? Ведь вопрос-то был о **разном управлении со стороны одного глагола**, насколько допустимо такое управление?

3. Попробуем переделать предложение: ***Им выносили колбасы, яиц, хлеба, свиного студня, телятины.*** Как-то невыразительно, не художественно звучит, хотя здесь  **семантика и грамматика** падежных форм одинаковая – это **родительный партитивный (разделительный) падеж.**
4. Р.п. часто используется при **переходных** глаголах вместо  винительного падежа, просто в случае В.п. действие  охватывает предмет полностью, а в случае Р.п. – только часть предмета. **Переходность** – важный признак глагола, и сочетаются эти глаголы только с сущ. в В.п или Р.п.

Писатель намеренно представляет однородный ряд предметов **в виде чередования разных грамматических форм** (слов и словосочетаний), так как словосочетание в форме В.п. и беспредложный Р.п. здесь выражают одинаковую **семантику** (значение партитивности).

Такие варианты **постоянно встречаются** в бытовых ситуациях, **вряд ли можно сомневаться** в их нормативности, например: купи хлеба, сыра и пакет молока.  Главное это то, что глагол **переходный**, а он **допускает две падежные формы**.

5. Есть ли в этом какой-то художественный смысл? Полагаю, что, уходя от невыразительного перечисления, писатель дает нам возможность **задержать внимание** на отдельных деталях и зрительно представить себе  всё это щедрое подаяние.

**«Мистика всё это!»** – можете сказать вы. Может быть, и так, но я вижу литературное произведение  **в художественных образах,** а не только в словах.

**Часть 3. Комментарий**

1. Таким образом, получен ответ на частный (конкретный) вопрос. Для **переходных** глаголов использование двух разных грамматических форм (Р.п.(партитивный) и В.п.) **возможно и широко применяется в речи**, так как семантика здесь **одинаковая**.

Но вопрос не решен в общем виде, то есть для непереходных глаголов и других падежей. Также падежные формы могут быть обстоятельством или обстоятельственным определением. Можно ли взять разные падежи и с**оставить из них однородные ряды дополнений, обстоятельств, определений**. Этот вопрос я оставляю открытым.

2. Удивительным кажется то, **как мы читаем вопросы** – каждый будто видит в них не общую суть, а какую-то конкретную деталь и фиксирует свое внимание на ней. Себя я тоже не исключаю в данном случае, надо было более четко оформить ответ.

**3. Цитата из другого ответа**

**"У @Sharon явное недоразумение.** Если взять за определение силлепса "семантическую неоднородность" (тут я не против, это общепринято), то каким образом в качестве вариантов этой "семантической неоднородности" рассматриваются "фразелологическая", "синтаксическая" и... "семантическая" неоднородность?! Для меня такие накладки сильно подрывают веру в написанное. Это безотносительно к моему мнению, что тут вообще никакой особой фигуры речи нет вовсе".

**Мне эта фраза удивительна.** В первой части ответа я подробно рассматриваю понятие силлепса, так как **он был заявлен в комментарии**, и делаю вывод, что в заданном предложении **нет силлепса**. Но это ничего не меняет. Перед автором ответа я несу **полную ответственность** за всё, что про это силлепс написано в Википедии (причем безотносительно к заданному вопросу и моему ответу на него).

Comment: Не думала я, что мой простенький вопрос вызовет такие споры. Собственно, споткнулась я вот на чём. _Им выносили яиц, хлеба, свиного студня, кусок телятины, отрезанное щедрой рукой кольцо колбасы._ Если бы предложение выглядело ТАК, то и вопроса, думаю, не возникло бы. А в предложении Куприна (при прочтении без большой паузы) словосочетание "кольцо колбасы" переносится и на "яиц", и на "хлеба" — кольцо колбасы, яиц, хлеба (как одно целое). Мне это показалось чудны́м.

Comment: Римма, наш язык чужд формальностей, и это его достоинство. Когда мы говорим про отрезанное щедрой рукой кольцо колбасы, мы воспринимаем это сочетание отдельно, оно по смыслу (да еще ввиду своей распространенности) никак не может относиться к другим членам ряда, хотя формально можно так подумать. Если бы мы заботились о подобных формальностях, наш язык был бы другим, более регламентированным и необоснованно сложным. Как мне кажется, мы очень многого достигли, уходя от формальной логики.

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу в примере из Куприна что-то особенного, тем более - какой-то фигуры речи.
Все разговоры о каком-то силлепсе представляются мне надуманными.

Давайте совсем простой пример.
***Я принес ей лекарство и воды.***
Да в любом художественном (и не только) тексте можно найти подобные примеры.
Ну что, простите, ***семантически*** неоднородного в двух составляющих этого короткого ряда? Только то, что первое конкретно, а второе - партитив. Но это разве что грамматическая неоднородность?
А если бы у Куприна было ***кольцо колбасы и пять яиц***? (я не предполагаю сводить объяснение к пропущенному числительному, это самостоятельный пример).
Неужели и тут будем искать семантическую неоднородность в том, что в первом элементе одна  штука объекта, а  во втором - несколько?!

А если, предположим, в компании детей три мальчика и девочка, то подлежащее в предложении ***"Девочка и мальчики играли в снежки"*** - тоже неоднородно?!

Короче, не вижу причин для какого-то особого внимания к подобным конструкциям. Они однородны, хотя формально и отвечают разным падежным вопросам.

(+) ===
И не могу пройти мимо (хотя и опасаюсь ставших, увы, привычными обвинений в переходе на личности).
У @Sharon явное недоразумение.
*Если взять за определение силлепса "семантическую неоднородность" (тут я не против, это общепринято), то каким образом в качестве вариантов этой "семантической неоднородности" рассматриваются "фразелологическая", "синтаксическая" и... "семантическая" неоднородность?!*
Для меня такие накладки сильно подрывают веру в написанное. Это безотносительно к моему мнению, что тут вообще никакой особой фигуры речи нет вовсе.

(++) ====
Есть у меня крамольная мысль, что родительный партитива на самом деле может отвечать на вопрос "что?" - как вариант  по меньшей мере. Это практически снимает все вопросы об однородности примера из Куприна. Но не буду настаивать, все-таки такие обязывающие и опасные для сложившихся моделей грамматике заявления без серьезной подготовки делать не следует.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119757/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus------).